# Deleting and Adding child entities in same transaction confusing nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, unit-of-work, ncommon

I'm getting the classic error:

```
'deleted object would be re-saved by cascade 
(remove deleted object from associations)[DrillingContracts.Domain.TrackedField#3216'
```

But with an added twist, The error is originating entirely because I'm deleting one entity and adding a NEW one.

I empty all the pre-existing children with this method

```
 public void RemoveChildren(TrackedNode parentNode)
        {
            foreach (TrackedField trackedField in parentNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                _trackedFieldRepository.Delete(trackedField);
                parentNode.RemoveChildNode(trackedField);
            }
        }
```

Then add the new ones immediately next

```
public virtual void AddTrackedChildFieldsToTrackedCell(
        params TrackedField[] nodes)
    {
        foreach (var field in nodes)
        {
            if (IsPath(field.Name))
            {
                throw new InvalidTrackedFieldNameException(
                    "The value " + field.Name + " is not a valid tracked field name.");
            }
                field.Supplement = this;
                _trackedFields.Add(field);
        }
    }
```

For those of you who want to know what is happening in the repository the best answer I have is magic. 10,000% magic. The original developer used NCommon. Both of these methods are called from a method wrapped in the NCommon.UnitOfWork attribute.

It should be noted that each method performs as expected on its own. (IE, no fields to delete the add works, and likewise, no fields to add the delete works.)

**EDIT**

```
[HttpPost]
[UnitOfWork(Scope = FilterScope.Result)]
public ActionResult SaveEditMode(long id, AddTrackedRowViewModel model, string editMode, List<string> elementNames, string provisionData)
        {
            var supplement = _supplementCoordinator.GetSupplement(id);
            var table = supplement.TrackedTables.First(x => x.Name == model.Name);

                var valueAttributes = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<ValueAttributeViewModel>>(provisionData);
                foreach (var prop in valueAttributes)
                {
                    supplement.Set(prop.Attribute, prop.Value, false);
                }

                var cell = table.TrackedRows.First(x => x.Ordinal == model.Ordinal).TrackedCells.First(x => x.Name == "Detail");
                _supplementCoordinator.RemoveChildren(cell);

                if (elementNames != null)
                {
                    var childNodes = elementNames.Select((t, i) => new TrackedField(cell, t, i)).ToList();
                    supplement.AddTrackedChildFieldsToTrackedCell(childNodes.ToArray());
                }


                return SwitchEditMode(model, editMode, table);
        }
```

**Answer**

```
public void AddChildren(Supplement supplement, TrackedNode parentNode, params TrackedField[] nodes)
    {
        foreach (TrackedField trackedField in nodes)
        {
            parentNode.AddChildNode(trackedField);

        }
        supplement.AddTrackedChildFieldsToTrackedCell();
    }
```

I wasn't getting them added as new entitles to the parent node, just the associated supplement.

Comment: You do not have to call `_trackedFieldRepository.Delete(trackedField);` We won't be deleting any item. Just replace the old Parent, and be sure, that the item was removed from the old Parent collection. No Delete() here!

Comment: @RadimKöhler Good catch. Now I just need to solve the big problem!

Comment: I assuemd it was still happening when the behavior remained the same, but the error message is now: "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)"

Comment: So, that's the progress! ;) in fact, it seems, that the operations you call are wrapped by transactions... and that could be a pain. Because what we need here is: 1) OpenSession 2) clear old parent collections 3) fill new parent collection 4) flush session... all at once

Comment: My biggest confusion, is why is it getting the new object confused with the old one? I'm going to add the outer method above in an edit.

Comment: I will tell you why! ;) The reason is pretty clear: the **cascade** mapping *(which I am sure you do have there)*. So the old parent, must be informed about changes... because otherwise it could cause weird behavior. or remove the cascade *(bad choice most likely)*. But, if you will do that all in the 4 steps I mentioned above, at-once, all in one session and transaction.. all will work properly

Comment: Yep. Thanks! Got it. Posting answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness. The message *'deleted object would be re-saved..'* was caused by the explicit call `session.Delete(instance)`.

In this case, we only need to 1) remove such item from the old parent collection and 2) append it to new parent. The cascade mapping and session.Flush() will properly upate DB.

Final note: such a "movement" must be done inside one session/transaction, to avoid other issues (e.g *'Row was updated or deleted by another transaction...'*).